# why doesn't XElement have a ToDictionary linq expression?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

For some reason ToDictionary isn't working.

I am using vs.net 2010 and 4.0

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(fullPathToXml);            
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = root.Elements("root");

var dic = nodes.ToDictionary(...)
```

I want to convert it to a `dictionary<string,string>`

it says there is no defintion for 'ToDictionary'...?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
using System.Linq;
```